# How can you read a gzipped parquet file in Python

Tags: python, hadoop, gzip, parquet

I need to open a gzipped file, that has a parquet file inside with some data. I am having so much trouble trying to print/read what is inside the file. I tried the following:

```
with gzip.open("myFile.parquet.gzip", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

This does not seem to work, as I get an error that my file id not a gz file. Thanks!

Comment: Two steps: 1) unzip it 2) use a lib that knows how to read parquet files like https://pypi.org/project/parquet/

Comment: unzipping doesn't work, this is what I already tried

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `read_parquet` function from `pandas` module:

1. Install `pandas` and `pyarrow`:

```
pip install pandas pyarrow
```

2. use `read_parquet` which returns `DataFrame`:

```
data = read_parquet("myFile.parquet.gzip")
print(data.count()) # example of operation on the returned DataFrame
```